# J2V8 and Stetho

Tags: android, debugging, v8, stetho, j2v8

I have an Android app using J2V8 and want to use Stetho to create a debug bridge I can use in Chrome dev tools.

Is there any documentation on how to connect Stetho to the V8 runtime I'm using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is still relevant - I have created [j2v8-debugger](https://github.com/AlexTrotsenko/j2v8-debugger) library.

It allows debugging `J2V8` using Chrome DevTools.

Basic features like setting/removing breakpoints, step into, step out and step over, variables inspection, etc. are implemented.

It uses *Stetho* lib for communication with *Chrome DevTools*.

Also it's uses *DebugHandler* for accessing *V8* debug information.

Hope it could be helpful.